# How Do I Allow My Program to Successfully Read The Numbers Contained a File?

Tags: c++, file, while-loop, numbers

I have been tasked with writing a program that reads the contents of a file full of numbers called random.txt which dislays those numbers and determines their sum, mean, and the number of numbers. However, the user must manually input the name of this file. When testing this program, it does not ever recognize that random.txt exists, and I do not know what is causing this. If there are any other logical errors int his program, I am unaware of them because I must first get the program to be able to read random.txt before I can view the results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i=0,num, sum=0;
double average;
ifstream input;
input.open("random.txt");           //open file
if(input.fail())             //is it ok?
   { cout<<"file did not open please check it\n";
    system("pause");
    return 1;
    }
input>>num;
while(input)
   {i++;
   sum+=num;
   input>>num;
   }
average=sum/(double)i;
cout<<"The number of numbers in the file is: "<<i<<endl;
   cout<<"The sum of all the numbers in the file is: "<<sum<<endl;
   cout<<"The average of all the numbers in the file: "<<average<<endl;
   input.close();
  system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

The code compiles in its current state, so I  do not receive any error messages despite the program not functioning as intended.

Comment: You placed a file called `random.txt` in some directory. Please show evidence that you are executing this program, which you compiled, from the same directory where the `random.txt` file is located.

Comment: *The code compiles* only indicates that the syntax is correct. It has no bearing on whether the logic is correct or not. And your text says *the user must manually input the name of this file*, but nowhere in your code do you accept user input to do so.

Answer (score 0):

in your while loop try this condition directly
it will work probably.

```
while(input >> number)
{
 i++;
 sum+=number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with a file "random.txt" with a list of random numbers and it works fine, so your code is not at fault.

That means you're compiling it wrong, or your executable file is located at a different folder than your random.txt file. The problem is probably the location of your random.txt file; make sure it is placed in the same directory where your compiled .exe file is being generated (some IDEs might output the binary file to a sub-folder inside your project).